# Dynamic Data in Eksternal CSS

Tags: php, html, css

I have a file eksternal css "**style.css**"

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" id="theme" href="css/style.css"/>
```

this part code is

```
.x-navigation > li.xn-logo > a:first-child {
  font-size: 0px;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  background: url("../img/logo.png") top center no-repeat #68A9CF;
  padding: 0px;
  border-bottom: 0px;
  color: #FFF;
  height: 60px;
  background-size: 180px 50px;
}
```

i want to change logo, but how to add dynamic data php in eksternal css,

i try like this, but doesn't work :(

```
<?php 
include "connection.php";
$dataweb = mysqli_query($con,"select logo from web");
$web = mysqli_feth_object($dataweb);
?>

.x-navigation > li.xn-logo > a:first-child {
  font-size: 0px;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  background: url("../img/<?php echo $web->logo ?>") top center no-repeat #68A9CF;
  padding: 0px;
  border-bottom: 0px;
  color: #FFF;
  height: 60px;
  background-size: 180px 50px;
}
```

Have a solution ??
Help me thank's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Php doesn't work in a .css file. It only works in .php file. So you have to do the following in the .php file within the *head* tag

```
<style>
background: url("../img/<?php echo $web->logo ?>") top center no-repeat #68A9CF;
</style>
```

and please use the  code at the first of the file to initiate the webroot.

```
<?php 
include "connection.php";
$dataweb = mysqli_query($con,"select logo from web");
$web = mysqli_feth_object($dataweb);
?>
```

It will replace the logo for you.

Comment: i know using in tag head
but i have many dynamic data in eksternal css. :(
like logo, logo small, color web, image user.etc

Comment: This is the only way I know. Because, you can't change the code of a .css file with php.

And it is ok, if you have many dynamic data in external css. Only add those css in the head tag which needs to be override and let the rest of the css be in the .css file. thats it.